# Intro Js help tour

Tags: javascript, intro.js

Is there a way to customize the bullets in intro js, such that user can be sure of which step its going to jump on?
I was asked if the bullets can have some kind of identification so that user can be sure when trying access help for the particular component.

http://jsfiddle.net/ee2s3p11/

The blue bullets are used for direct navigation to the steps, if some how those blue bullets can be customized, it would be easier for user to jump to the help component they are looking for.

Step 1
    
     Step 2 



    Step 3
    
     Step 4

Click Me!

```
.introjs-tooltip {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
} 
.introjs-bullets ul li a {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25389874/3364926

Comment: Let me know if the question was unclear,I have just started working with intro js, I will try to be clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
.introjs-bullets ul li a:after {
  content: attr(data-stepnumber);
  color:#fff; position:relative; top:-2px;left:-2px;
}
```

See the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ee2s3p11/1/

Comment: Thanks Gary. I was thinking of something where if you hover on the bullets, content related to data-intro specific to the step can be displayed on a tool-tip (kind of). For now I would accept this as the best answer available. Thanks again!

Comment: You could add another `data-` element like `data-hint` and use something like `.introjs-bullets ul li a:hover:after {content: attr(data-hint);}`  I think you get the idea....  Or write a script that loops through and adds a `title` attribute to the `<a>` tag.  That automatically shows on hover.  Either way, good luck!

Comment: @Maddy Any particular reason you unaccepted this as the answer?

Comment: sorry I think I did it accidentally. I wanted to put my answer as well, I accepted that answer. Later I deleted it though. I don't know, may be we can have just one accepted answer. I didn't realise yours got unaccepted.

Comment: @Maddy  No problem.  I was just wondering if the code didn't work for you.